# How to use Anko DSL inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, anko

The [Github wiki page](https://github.com/JetBrains/anko#basics) show this example to be used in `Activity` instance:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    verticalLayout {
        padding = dip(30)
        editText {
            hint = "Name"
            textSize = 24f
        }
        editText {
            hint = "Password"
            textSize = 24f
        }
        button("Login") {
            textSize = 26f
        }
    }
}
```

How to do the same inside a `Fragment`?

I tried to put that `verticalLayout` block in `onCreateView` but the method cannot be resolved. I have added `anko-support-v4` dependency, but still no luck.

Comment: try to navigate to the `verticalLayout` method. My guess is that it is defined on `Activity`, so it works inside it, but not outside it.

Comment: If what I said is true, than a solution would be to try assigning the layout to an appropriate property. In your example it kind of hangs in the air

Comment: @voddan yes, it's only available in `Activity`. Finally, I've found a workaround, will post the answer soon

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After digging up `anko-support-v4` source code plus some trial and errors, I have found a workaround although I'm not sure if it's the right/recommended way. It seems a little undocumented.

A sample from my `Fragment` code:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    return UI {
        verticalLayout {
            linearLayout {
                avatar = imageView().lparams(width = dip(48), height = dip (48))
                name = textView().lparams(width = 0, weight = 1f)
            }

            linearLayout {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }.toView()
}
```

> I'm returning layout DSL wrapped in `UI { ... }.toView()` in `Fragment.onCreateView(...)`

Comment: I recommend you asking more on the intended use of API at the slack channel, #anko thread: http://kotlinslackin.herokuapp.com/. Because for me this inconsistency seems like a bug, but people there know for sure.

Comment: Yes, it is the right way for the current version of Anko (0.7.3).

Comment: @netimen just return ```UI{}.view```

Answer (score 21):

With Anko 0.8 you can also use an `AnkoComponent`, if you want to hold your UI in a separate class so you can reuse it elsewhere.

```
class FragmentUi<T>: AnkoComponent<T> {
    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<T>) = with(ui) {
        verticalLayout {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can call it in your fragment `onCreateView()` by

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View
        = FragmentUi<Fragment>().createView(AnkoContext.create(ctx, this))
```

Comment: `AnkoContext.create(ctx, this)` is deprecated. instead of `ctx` one should use `requireContext()`

Answer (score 7):

As of anko 0.8.1 the correct code would be:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    return UI {
        verticalLayout {
            linearLayout {
                // ...
            }
            linearLayout {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }.view
}
```

Comment: it says it want it when the ? in LayoutInflater is deleted